# c code on task scheduling

Tags: c

I want to execute this code to run auto taskscheduling as this code has two errors.  I'm not able to figure out the corrections.

Errors are "(in function 'main')" and "(invalid lvalue in assignment)"

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char *timetoken;
    char currtime[7];
    char schedtime[9];
    int i;
    struct tm *localtimeptr;
    strcpy(schedtime,"15:25:00");
    while(true)
    {
        time_t lt;
        sleep(1);
        time(&lt);
        localtimeptr = localtime(&lt);
        timetoken=strtok(asctime(localtimeptr)," ");
        for(i=1;i<5;i++)
            timetoken=strtok(NULL," ");
        if(i==3)
        {
            strcpy(currtime,timetoken);
        }
    }
    printf("The current time is: %s\n",currtime);
    printf("We are waiting for: %s\n",schedtime);
    if(!strcmp(currtime,schedtime))
    {
        printf("Time to do stuff \n");
        system("ROBOCOPY C:\\oslab E:\\BACKUP /e/mir/np /log:backup_log.txt");
    }        
    getch();
    return 0;                      
}
```

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: error on 18th line.

Comment: What have you tried? For instance, did you learn about what an lvalue is, and determine what is being used as an lvalue on the line where the error occurred, and consider whether it is a valid lvalue? Also, please format your code correctly.

Comment: When you post a question here, you should always post the error verbatim, and also point out the lines affected in code you post.

Answer (score 0):

`time = (&lt);`

You didn't define a variable called `time`... are you sure this wasn't meant to set a different variable?

Comment: `while(6!=9)` also looks mighty strange. 6 will never be 9, no matter how many times you check!

Comment: :i referred to this link here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/localtime/ and wrote the code

Comment: That's fine, but regardless of how `localtime` works, 6 will always be 6, no more and no less. `if(i==3)` will never be true either.

Answer (score 0):

```
time = (&lt);
```

You're trying to assign to `time`, but you yourself have never declared anything called `time`.  Accordingly, you're trying to reassign `time(3)` from `time.h`.

Maybe you mean something else in this line, like

```
time(&lt);
```